# call command for bat script not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Essentially I have two .bat scripts that work just fine individually, however I wanted to combine the two scripts into one action as i have it assigned to a hotkey and want all of this with one press of a key, not two but am having problems because the scripts are in different directories.

Below are my two scripts:

**BLAH-Script.bat**

```
RE4_UHD_BLAH_Tool.exe -p
DEL /F /S /Q /A "F:\r101\r101_09.AEV"
```

and the second script:

**UDAS_TOOL.bat**:

```
DEL /F /S /Q /A "F:\st1\rl01.udas"
ping -n 1 localhost
DEL /F /S /Q /A "F:\UDAS Tool\r101.udas"
UDAS_Tool.exe -p
```

Now, both of these work great on their own because each of the scripts calls on an .exe that is in the same DIR as the script that calls them, but trying to get them into one .bat file has not worked using the `CALL` function because one of the scripts exists in an outside directory.

I have tried to make a new .bat script that would execute both bat scripts in one:

```
call "F:\pack\BLAH-Script.bat"
ping -n 1 localhost
call "F:\pack\UDAS\UDAS_TOOL.bat"
```

However this does not work.The files are not packaged by the exe tools as intended.

To try and figure out the problem I added `pause` command between scripts:

```
call "F:\pack\BLAH-Script.bat"
pause
call "F:\pack\UDAS_TOOL.bat"
```

This command allowed me to read the output before the window was closed and yielded the culprit. In the first script I am getting the following error:

***F:\UD - r101-->RE4_UHD_BLAH_Tool.exe -p
'RE4_UHD_BLAH_Tool.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.***

I believe what is happening it that each file works fine if run in its own directory because they are in the same DIR as the .exe they are calling, but the first .bat file will not execute because the third bat file ( the one that is that is calling the first & second) is not in the same DIR as the first.

I have tried:

```
CD /D "F:\pack"   
call "F:\pack\BLAH-Script.bat"
pause
CD /D "F:\pack"
call "F:\pack\UDAS\UDAS_TOOL.bat"
```

with the same error.
How do I get the directories sorted out ?

Comment: Please tell us **what happened** - what the script did that it shouldn't have done, what it didn't do that it should have done. "does not work" is a useless message - if it had, you wouldn't be asking for help. I suspect that the first script is changing the current directory, but without seeing the scripts and a clear description, it's just a guess.

Comment: i think you are correct about the directory idea, as both scripts are in different places, hence the quotations. As for it 'not working' I will elaborate in my question now.

Comment: @Magoo ok i refined the question to reflect the issue better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you could simply fully-qualify the executable path, or make sure that the executables are located on the `path`.

However, some programs *assume* that the executable is in the current directory, and expect that configuration files, etc. are similarly in that directory, so what I'd do is

in each batch, after the initialisation ceremony (@echo off/setlocal...) add a

```
pushd "actualexcutablelocation"
```

and ensure that on exit from the batch,

```
popd
```

is executed to restore to the original directory.

`pushd` switches current directory to the nominated directory until a `popd` is executed to return to the original.

Comment: This worked in the third script.. Adding `pushd "path_to_folder_that_contains_exe"` before each command to run the scripts. Thank you

Comment: Can't advise on the `path specified` problem - your machine appears to feel that the directory you have specified does not exist. Note that the quotes are not required (I include them through habit on the principle of quoting directory/filenames that may include separators) - this *can* be caused by using an editor that repaces quotes with "smart quotes" in which case, use a proper edito like `notepad++` or `editplus` (amongst others). Personally, I'd put the `pushd/popd` bracket within each batch file so that each batch will run on its own & cascading them is simply `call batch1&call batch2`